# WinJS - How do I access LED Flash (on windows phone)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, windows-phone, winjs

I am new to WinJS and am trying to develop an app that uses LED Flash. I need help in accessing the LED Flash, in order to switch it ON or OFF.

Please explain how I can access LED Flash using WinJS.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want this API:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.devices.torchcontrol.ASPx

dev.windows.com is the place to go for the WinRT API reference, where you can find how to do things like this. They also have a pretty extensive sample library.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, This API does not work on all devices even if this property (torchControl.powerSupported) returns true